# how to know the direction of rotation of UIImage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, rotation

i want to rotate the uiimage in the direction turned, i'm able to get the angle between touchesBegan and TouchesEnd points but how should i decide whether to rotate cockwise or anti-clockwise? 
Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Get the current orientation of the device and rotates as you wish.

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

*orientation* is *UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft* and *UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight* if the device is on landscape.

Comment: no, its not the orientation turn i need. i need to turn the image to the angle rotated, but hw ll i decide, to rotate in left direction or right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I don't know how you get the angle, how you want to rotate the image (via accelerometer or touching) and what is the problem.

Comment: i want to turn the imageview without rotating the device.